# How to use App Service methods as REST API endpoints?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, http-method

POST `/api/services/app/Company/Create` is the URL we normally get when we create App Service in ASP.NET Boilerplate.

How can I achieve POST `/api/services/app/Company` using App Service? Because if I use OData, then some response format is not in ABP response format.

Here, POST is the HTTP method and `Create` is the name of the method in `CompanyAppService` of my ABP Application project. What I want is when I consume this API on any web app, then I should be able to call this API at `/api/services/app/Company` with HTTP method POST. I don't want to use `Create`, `Update`, `Delete`, `Get`, `GetAll` in URL that we are going to use while calling in web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by following way.

```
[HttpPost("api/services/app/Company")]
public async Task CreateCompany(CompanyDetailsDto input)

[HttpDelete("api/services/app/Company")]
public async Task DeleteCompany(EntityDto input)

[HttpGet("api/services/app/Company")]
public async Task GetCompany(EntityDto input)

[HttpPut("api/services/app/Company")]
public async Task UpdateCompany(CompanyDetailsDto input)
```